# Why do I get a different type dependant on when I evaluate a JavaScript variable in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

I would like to understand why the `typeof` a JavaScript `variable` is different depending on where I `evaluate` it, even though I have't changed it.

I have a object like this:

```
var model = {}
model.user = {}
model.caller = {}
model.caller.name = 'Batman';
model.other = {}
// etc
```

I pass it into a child Lightning component like this:

```
$A.createComponent(screen, {
        "aura:id" : "activeScreen",
        "model" : model
    }, function (contentComponent, status, error) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            target.set('v.body', [contentComponent]);
        } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    });
```

It's stored in this attribute in the child component:

```
<aura:attribute name="model" type="Object" />
```

And in the child component get the model using this helper method:

```
model : function(cmp) {
    return cmp.get("v.model");
},
```

If I call this method and check the `typeof` the value return:

```
var model = helper.model(cmp);
console.log(typeof model);
```

I get an console out put of:

> string

Whereas, if I evaluate the value within the helper method:

```
model : function(cmp) {

    var model = cmp.get("v.model");

    switch (typeof model){
        case 'string':
            console.log('string');  
            return JSON.parse(cmp.get("v.model"));

        case 'object':
            console.log('object');  
            return cmp.get("v.model");
    }

    return null;
},
```

The console out put is:

> object

Why do I get a different `type` dependant on when I evaluate it?

Comment: Declaration of the `aura:attribute` model in the child component please.

Comment: @N.B. Added the attribute

Comment: Likely to be caused by LockerService proxying. See e.g. [How Locker Service Uses the Proxy Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm). One of these [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) functions should give you the underlying object.

Comment: @KeithC I imagined it might would be the LockerService... but I am still not sure why the LockerService is making it behaves like this in this case and what set of rules I can rely on.

Comment: The first link in my comment provides some of the rules.

Comment: @KeithC thanks, I read that yesterday and I have a basic grasp on LockerService and the object Proxy object type it uses. Therefore I would expect to always get an `object` when I use `cmp.get` but this question illustrates that it not always the case. And I don't yet understand why and the link provided doesn't clear that up (unless I am miss-understanding something, which may be the case)

Comment: My guess is that the behaviour is probably changing as performance/debugability is tuned and the documentation can't keep up or the detailed behavior is "non-API". Probably best to use a different strategy in your code to avoid being dependent on the details of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to:

> Why do I get a different `type` dependant on when I evaluate it?

But if you are battling this issue, the below might help.

---

By setting the `attribute` type to `string` I consistently get an `object`

```
<aura:attribute name="model" type="String" />
```

Seem backwards... but it works... at the moment (June 2018)

Comment: Definitely don't do that. It may work today, but there's no guarantee it will work later.

Comment: @sfdcfox Shall I delete this post then?

Comment: Were I you, I'd ask around on Twitter, Communities, or something, see if anyone knows what's going on. I wouldn't go so far as to delete this yet. I'm not sure I have an answer for you, but I'm pretty sure that using a String attribute and expecting an Object back out is not a good idea.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks. I think setting an attribute to `String` and getting an `Object` is bonkers ;)